# for loop not working as expected C#

Tags: c#

I am working on this `for` loop but I encountered a problem which seriously is bothering me. When the `for` loop is executed it should return

```
{"MonID":"1","MonMapID":0}
{"MonID":"1","MonMapID":1}
{"MonID":"1","MonMapID":2}
{"MonID":"1","MonMapID":3}
```

But it's not returning that it's returning exactly

```
{"MonID":"1","MonMapID":3}
{"MonID":"1","MonMapID":1}
{"MonID":"1","MonMapID":2}
{"MonID":"1","MonMapID":3}
```

Here's the code which I ran

```
JObject mapMonBranch = new JObject();
JArray monList = new JArray();
string[] monB = room.Mon.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
for (int index = 0; index < monB.Length; index++)
{
    var monData = monB[index];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(monData)) continue;

    mapMonBranch ["MonID"] = monData;
    mapMonBranch ["MonMapID"] = index;
    monList.Add(mapMonBranch);
}
```

What's the problem with the code? I am seriously confused.

Comment: What does `room.Mon` look like?

Comment: What is `mapMon`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Fyi, Instead of `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(monData)) continue;` use the other `String.Split` overload: `room.Mon.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: You are adding `mapMonBranch` to `monList`, but that does not appear elsewhere in the loop, you also set `mapMon`, which is also not otherwise referenced in the loop.

Comment: if MapMon is a Dictionary, you can't garantee elements order

Comment: I have added the mapMon its a JObject updated the answer with all the code it needs.

Comment: No you have not you still use `mapMonBranch` and it is not declared anywhere in your code.

Comment: I think you can replace `Convert.ToChar(",")` with just `','`

Comment: I edited the code ... it should have everything...

Comment: It does not have mapMonBranch !!

Comment: Heres a pic of the updated code.... http://prntscr.com/a6zk9a

Comment: Please show us what mapMonBranch is - that would help more than a picture of the code you have already posed

Comment: JObject mapMonBranch = new JObject();

Comment: So, you create empty JObject, never set any of its properties, then add to monList?

Comment: No updated the code should fine now sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding four references to the same object to your list. Adding to the list adds a reference to the object, it does not create a new copy of that object, so if you modify that object all entries in the list will change. You need to create a new instance of the object each time you want to add one for example :

```
JArray monList = new JArray();
string[] monB = room.Mon.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
for (int index = 0; index < monB.Length; index++)
{
    var monData = monB[index];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(monData)) continue;

    JObject mapMonBranch = new JObject();
    mapMonBranch["MonID"] = monData;
    mapMonBranch["MonMapID"] = index;
    monList.Add(mapMonBranch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new instance of your mapmon object inside the loop, like so:

```
JObject mapMonBranch = new JObject();
JArray monList = new JArray();
JObject mapMon = new JObject();
string[] monB = room.Mon.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
for (int index = 0; index < monB.Length; index++)
{
    var monData = monB[index];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(monData)) continue;

    mapmon = new JObject(); 
    mapMon["MonID"] = monData;
    mapMon["MonMapID"] = index;
    monList.Add(mapMonBranch);
}
```